# PHP won't receive POST requests at /directory/ only at /directory/index.php

Tags: php

When POST request are sent to "http://domain.com/directory/", the POST data isn't received. But if it's sent to "http://domain.com/directory/index.php" it is received.

How can I make it work when just the directory is called? Thanks!

Comment: There's no reason why it wouldn't get the POST on that request, the only thing I can think of is a possible redirect, maybe if you've set up some funky .htaccess files..

Comment: If you open "http://domain.com/directory/" in a browser window, do you see content at that address, does it show an error message, or does the browser address change to "http://domain.com/directory/index.php"?

Comment: Another possible source of redirection is using "/directory" instead of "/directory/". Forgetting the trailing slash can trigger a redirect as well.

Comment: @James, I am not a php guy but in asp.net there is a url rewriter, if you are using like that technique then there is a chance that your post request is being redirected which lost the post data

Comment: Are you on linux or on windows? I remember once I had a similar problem on IIS.

Comment: @Lucanos: Yes @janmoesen: Not the problem.

Comment: Lazlo: You can’t just answer “Yes” to Lucanos 3 ORs. It should definitely be a redirection issue. So, if you’re familiar with browsers dev-tools use them. Check the Net tab in whatever you’re using and see the requests with and without post data.

Comment: Here's a link to others that had a similar problem: [Missing post variables](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Web_Servers/Apache/Q_22893159.html) You have to scroll a long way down the page to see most of the comments, and you might have to subscribe to see the selected answer, but perhaps there are some clues. For some, using SSLVerifyClient require and SSLVerifyDepth 1 caused this issue.

Comment: I did what @janmoesen suggested and that worked for me :)

Answer (score 6):

If you're running Apache, check if the mod_dir module is enabled and configured correctly. These are the contents of my dir.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Also this rules could be located in .htaccess under /directory/

Comment: But I can see index.php when I just access the directory, that's not the problem. Only the post is lost.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using a tool like HttpFox for Firefox to see if when you make a request to the directory on its own, you are being redirected? I know a redirect can kill a POST request as it gets converted into a GET request.

Answer (score 4):

As Lucanos said, is the web server redirecting to `index.php`? POST data might get "lost" between pages if you redirect. Try GET and check if the URL ends with correct data.

Answer (score 3):

Create ".htaccess" file inside   /directory/ with this content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

It tells server to route all request that are physically not possible (since no file or folder exist for that request) to index.php , advantage of this is that your .css file .js , .jpg files wont get routed to index.php .

Answer (score 0):

If the directory contains index.html alongwith index.php, just rename the index.html file else delete the file because if you give the path to directory only, the index.html always gets enabled no matter the index.php still exists in the same directory.

Comment: No, not always, it depends on the order of the DirectoryIndex setting in Apache